# Sketchup Get Entity By component name

Tags: ruby, sketchup

To work on an element, I use the following for the definition.

```
ref = Sketchup.active_model.entities[0]
refdef = ref.definition
```

is there a way in which I can get the entitiy by its name (component name) instead of entities[0] etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Sketchup.active_model.definitions`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/model#definitions) returns a [DefinitionList](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/definitionlist). Its [`[]`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/definitionlist#[]) method can be used to access definitions by `index`, `GUID` or `name`.

```
componame="MyLovelyComponent"
compo = Sketchup.active_model.definitions[componame]
if compo
    puts "#{componame} found: doing something else..."
    ### do something with 'compo' definition
else
   puts "#{componame} does NOT exist!"
   return
end
```